# Can a class variable be used inside an object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, class, kotlin, object

I'm trying to utilize the variables of a class inside an object, but the function inside the object cannot access this "mockStatus" variable that is part of the HttpService class, is there any way I can obtain that value inside the object in Kotlin?

```
class HttpService(private val mappedEnvironmentsConfig: MappedEnvironmentsConfig) {
    final val dalapiProperties = mappedEnvironmentsConfig.get().`dal-api`
    val mockStatus = dalapiProperties.`use-mock-data`
    val mockPath = dalapiProperties.`mock-data-path`

    object testInterceptor : FoldableRequestInterceptor {
       override fun invoke(next: RequestTransformer): RequestTransformer {
        return { request ->
            var example = mockStatus
            ///
            next(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior? You can have several `HttpService` instances and each of them could have a different `mockStatus` value. `testInterceptor` is a singleton, it is not related to any specific `HttpService` instance, so how could it reference `mockStatus` of one of services? Maybe your intention was to use an inner class instead of a singleton object?

Comment: `testInterceptor` can't be an `object` anymore. Is that ok?